# Program crashes when printing LinkedList

Tags: c, string, list, pointers, printing

I have a double linked list in C, which's nodes hold a char*.
My struct for the node looks like this:

```
struct LinkedListNode{
char* data;
LinkedListNode* next;
LinkedListNode* prev; };
```

The struct for the LinkedList looks like this:

```
struct LinkedList{
LinkedListNode* head;
LinkedListNode* tail;};
```

head is a pointer to the first node of the list, tail is a pointer to the last node of the list. My problem is that I am trying to write a function for testing some standard functions for linked lists, which I am implementing for practice purposes. So I start by generating a list in the following function:

```
LinkedList* make_test_list(){
LinkedList* newlist = LinkedList_create();
printf("Hier2");
LinkedListNode n1;
LinkedListNode n2;
LinkedListNode n3;
LinkedListNode n4;
LinkedListNode n5;
n1.data = "abc";
n2.data = "def";
n3.data = "ghi";
n4.data = "pqr";
n5.data = "mno";
n1.next = &n2;
n2.next = &n3;
n2.prev = &n1;
n3.next = &n4;
n3.prev = &n2;
n4.next = &n5;
n4.prev = &n3;
n5.prev = &n4;
n5.next = NULL;
newlist->head = &n1;
newlist->tail = &n5;
return newlist;}
```

Which appears to be working fine, since I can reaccess the data of each node, if I try to print it inside of this function.
LinkedList_create() contains the following code:

```
LinkedList* LinkedList_create(){
LinkedList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
list->head = NULL;
list->tail = NULL;
return list;
}
```

So the next thing I want to do is printing my list in a seperate function.
The function looks like this:

```
void LinkedList_print(LinkedList* list){    
LinkedListNode* p = list->head;
while(p != NULL)){
    printf("%s\n", p->data);
    p = p->next;
}}
```

But somehow it doesn't work. I think that I made a mistake while assigning my pointers. The call looks like this:

```
int main(){
LinkedList* myList = make_test_list();
printf("List before: \n");

LinkedList_print(myList);
}
```

I'd be glad if you could help me out on this one, since I'm quite new to C and new to managing memory allocation by myself.

Cheers!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Don't describe your code, show it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinkedListNode` variables (`n1`-`n5`) are local to the `make_test_list` function.  You need to allocate memory for them if you want to access them outside of that function.

For example:

```
LinkedListNode *n1 = malloc(sizeof(*n1));
n1->data = "abc";
...
newlist->head = n1;
...
```

Of course, you also want to make sure you `free` the memory later.  I am also making the assumption that `LinkedList_create` is implemented correctly, since it isn't shown here.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero!